# Is it cheaper to reverse an appended list or to prepend a list? - python

Tags: python, list, insert, reverse, prepend

**Which is faster and more pythonic?**

- reverse an appended list
- start prepending the list from the start
- using `deque`

E.g. here's ome made-up data to store into a new list

```
# Let's say my function outputs these output individually.
x = [12,34,44,346,345,876,123]
```

Reversing an appended list:

```
new_list = []
for i in x:
  new_list.append(i)
new_list = newlist[::-1]
```

Prepending to the list:

```
new_list = [] 
for i in x:
  new_list.insert(0,i)
```

Using deque:

```
from collections import deque
for i in x:
  x.appendleft(i)
```

Please note that my question is not how to reverse list. Please also assume that the list is of size ~20,000.

Comment: Why not `timeit` and see?

Comment: Any specific reason you don't want to use a `deque`?

Comment: Rather than a `for` loop, you could directly use `new_list = x[::-1]`, or `new_list = list(x)[::-1]` if `x` isn't a list, or loop over `reversed(list(x))` if you don't actually need a list out of this.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I have `timeit` but it's quite similar...

Comment: `list(reversed(x))` would be the fastest

Comment: @user2357112, because the function was yielding, i'm not sure whether realizing a list and reversing is faster than prepending.

Comment: inserting is always going to be  very slow, you have to repeatedly move all elements on each insertion

Comment: @alvas: You must have timed it wrong, then, because the difference is enormous.

Comment: first example `1.69 ms` second `128 ms` `list(reversed)` `129 µs` on 20k element list

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: You can't call `reversed` on arbitrary iterables, though.

Comment: @user2357112, I don't get what you mean, `list(reversed(x))` returns a reversed list

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: But `x` is a generator. You can't call `reversed` on that.

Comment: @user2357112 where does it say x is a generator?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: One of alvas's comments says "because the function was yielding, i'm not sure whether realizing a list and reversing is faster than prepending." That seems to indicate it's a generator. For a list, `x[::-1]` outperforms `list(reversed(x))`.

Comment: @user2357112, you are right, either way reversing would be considerably faster than inserting

Comment: The `deque` is going to be much faster than either of the alternatives; O(1) appendleft operations are pretty much the entire point of it existing... Of course, you don't say what you plan to do with this data structure after you build it. If accessing arbitrary elements by index is one of the things you want to be able to do easily, you'll lose the efficiency you got in building the thing while using it.

Answer (score 4):

Your first method could be simplified to one line :

```
new_list = x[::-1]
```

Then, to check which method is faster than any other, just use `timeit` (tested with python 2.7.8) :

```
C:\>python -m timeit -s "x = [12,34,44,346,345,876,123]" "new_list = x[::-1]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.215 usec per loop

C:\>python -m timeit -s "x = [12,34,44,346,345,876,123]; new_list = []" "for i in x:" "  new_list.insert(0,i)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 146 usec per loop

C:\>python -m timeit -s "from collections import deque; x = [12,34,44,346,345,876,123]; new_list = deque()" "for i in x:" "  new_list.appendleft(i)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.713 usec per loop

C:\>python -m timeit -s "x = [12,34,44,346,345,876,123]" "new_list = list(reversed(x))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.837 usec per loop
```

So `new_list = x[::-1]` is better than any other way.

You also have to ask yourself if you want to "reference" or "copy" elements into the new list structure.

Comment: `list(reverse(x))` is somewhere between method #1 and #3.

Comment: it's `list(reversed(x))` I add it to the answer.

Comment: FYI, on my machine with python3 at least, deque is slightly faster than append and reverse (510nsec vs 674nsec). This answer short-circuits the append and reverse option (by doing a reversed copy, which is NOT the same thing in the general sense), and so does not give any timings for that scenario.